# Creating a class for a new view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

My Xcode project came with a default:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
```

I then created a new view controller with the id `next`.

How can I create a class like the one the project had already created, but for my view controller `next`?

I thought it would look something like:

```
class next: UIviewcontroller
```

Comment: Did you look at the duplicate question that was linked to your previous question?  The answer to it explains how to create the class code for your second view controller and link that code to the view controller in the storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want to do, then you need to create a class `NextViewController` and override methods `viewDidLoad` and `didReceiveMemoryWarning` like this:

```
class NextViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

And then at your storyboard in `Identity inspector` tab select the created class for your `ViewController` like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, however I haven't gotten it to work even though Im sure your code is exactly what I need. Do you know what I'm doing wrong here?
    `class Next: UIViewController {
        @IBOutlet weak var Levels: UILabel!
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
        }
        
        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        }
        
        class stageOne {
        Levels.text "test" //whats can be wrong here.
        }
    }
 }
`

Comment: I can't figure out how to make my code here look more readable... I'm sorry.

Comment: I must have done something awful, because now it won't access my next view from the click on my label, which always has worked.

Comment: @Frederic What is `stageOne`? It's looks like a `class` but why it inside the `Next` and what you want to do on it?

Comment: I figured it all out, to be honest I can't explain half of the stuff. I'm kind off at the "trial and error" thing.. but I made it all work out so far :). Thanks for the help, once again.